# didn't get my column values against my column attributes in sparql

Tags: sparql, owl, protege4

Can anyone help me in sparql. I'm working on ontology based project. I've a structure in protege-owl like

```
City-hasWeatherConditions-(multiple value i.e temp,dewpoint)
```

I want to get values against each attribute.

#### Query:

```sql
PREFIX pro: <http://www.semanticweb.org/computer/ontologies/2019/0/fyp.owl#> 
select ?indi ?val
where
{
   {
        select ?indi
        where
        {
         pro:Lahore
         <http://www.semanticweb.org/computer/ontologies/2019/0/fyp.owl#hasWeatherCondition>
         ?indi
         }
   }
  {
         select ?val
         where 
        {
           <http://www.semanticweb.org/computer/ontologies/2019/0/fyp.owl#DewPoint>
           <http://www.semanticweb.org/computer/ontologies/2019/0/fyp.owl#hasDewPoint>
            ?val
         }
  }
}
```

#### Figure1: Note -- 5.21 is DewPoint value which is repeated in temp.

[image: Figure1]

#### Figure2:

[image: Figure2]

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Please show sample data and the expected result. And I don't understand why you have two sub queries. Both query totally different things, thus, there will be no relationship in the final result. That can't be intended and will just return the cartesian

Comment: I've dataset like
City : Lahore,Islamabad etc.
Weather Conditions: Temperature,DewPoint,Humidity etc.
Weather Condition attributes has individual of its class name. e.g
Temperature (individual)-hasTemp (DataProperty)-(Some Integer Value).
Now I want when i query on Lahore(Individual of City) via property has Weather Conditions, all weather Conditions should come with their assigned values.
Please find attachment
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/elT7P.png

Comment: not sure if I understood everything, but then you should continue with `?indi` variable and get triples attached to each weather condition. Something like `?indi pro:hasDewPoint ?val`. SPARQL is about subgraph pattern matching. The query should be `PREFIX pro: <http://www.semanticweb.org/computer/ontologies/2019/0/fyp.owl#> 
select ?indi ?val
where
{
         pro:Lahore   pro:hasWeatherCondition         ?indi. ?indi pro:hasDewPoint ?val
         
   }`

Comment: If this query above doesn't work, please show the RDF data and not a graph where I can't see the property names etc.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words, help us to help you.

Comment: Note that the fact that the `DewPoint` and `Temperature` of `Lahore` have the same value of `"5.21"^^xsd:float` is coincidental. There is no connection in the graph between `DewPoint` and `Temperature` (aside from an unfortunate overlap in the illustration).

Comment: Let me try to explain one more time.
I'm attaching snapshots of my ontology. Hope it will create more understanding to you.
1. Classes and Individuals.
Fig 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tR2l.png
2. Object Properties (Domain Range of WeatherConditions)
Fid 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecqcs.png
3.Data property and Domain Ranges (hasDewpoint and all instances of Weather Condition have same Domain but diff values)
Fig 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAqVs.png
4. Let's take example for City Lahore. it has characteristics
Fig 4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6oHk.png
Sorry I'm new at semantic.

Comment: I want to get results like 
when i query for:
Lahore has Weather Conditions (i.e query should give me all weather conditions with their assigned values.)
Thanks for your support!